# Not able to read rpt file using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpt

I am trying to read a .rpt file using the python code:

```
>>> with open(r'C:\Users\lenovo-pc\Desktop\training2.rpt','r',encoding = 'utf-8', errors = 'replace') as d:
...     count = 0
...     for i in d.readlines():
...         count = count + 1
...         print(i+"\n")
...
...


u

i

d

|

e

x

p

i

d

|

n

a

m

e

|

d

o

m

a

i

n
```

And I am getting the following result as mentioned above.
Kindly, let me know how I can read the .rpt file using python3.

Comment: did you mean `for i in d.readlines()`?

Comment: @asongtoruin yeah

Comment: Does that fix your issue??

Comment: Nope ... it doesn't. I tried that too

Comment: Can you post the result you get when using `d.readlines()` rather than `d.readline()`?

Comment: Exactly the same. There is no difference. I have already posted that in the question.

Comment: Your code in the question uses `d.readline()`. I am suggesting that you use `d.readlines()` - note the s. At present your question contains no reference to the plural, line-splitting `d.readlines()`

Comment: I tried that too. Let me edit and make it `readlines()` I think then you will understand it, my friend.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the contents of the .rpt file too? This behaviour seems unusual

Comment: Why are you adding a newline? The `print` function will include a newline unless you override that behavior with the `end` keyword argument. Anak what do you elect the file to look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is, indeed, strange behavior. While I can not easily reproduce the error without knowing the format of the .rpt file here are some hints what might go wrong. I assume it looks something like this:

```
uid|expid|name|domain
...
```

Which can be read and printed with the following code:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\lenovo-pc\Desktop\training2.rpt','r',encoding = 'utf-8', errors = 'replace') as rfile:
    count = 0
    for line in rfile:
        count += 1
        print(line.strip())  # this removes white spaces, line breaks etc.
```

However, the problem seems to be that you iterate over the string of the first line in your file instead of the lines in the file. That would produce the patter of you see, as the `print()` function adds a line break (in addition to the one you add manually). This leaves you with on character per line (followed by two line breaks).

```
>>> for i in "foo":
...     print(i+"\n")
f

o

o
```

Make sure you did not reuse variable names from earlier in the session and do not overwrite the file object.